# Is there a name for the follow function $\frac{x}{1+x^2}$

Tags: functions

Is there a name for the follow function $\frac{x}{1+x^2}$?

Or the integral of $\frac{x}{1+x^2}$ is a typical function?

Comment: It's an irriducible partial fraction for sure...

Comment: $\frac{x}{1+x^2}=\frac{1}{2i}(\frac{1}{1-ix}-\frac{1}{1+ix})$

Comment: @Khosrotash I don't really think such a basic question could use a fraction decomposition *in the complex numbers field* ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The function is a *rational funcion* defined on the whole real line, and its integral is a rather well known function ( I don't know what "typical function" may mean ):

$$\int\frac x{1+x^2}dx=\frac12\int\frac{d(x^2+1)}{1+x^2}=\frac12\log(1+x^2)+C$$

Answer (score 1):

Another fun fact about this function is that $$e^x \star \frac{x}{1+x^2} = \sin(x),$$ where the $\star$ is Hadamard product of power series, defined as follows:

$$\left(\sum_{i \in \mathbb{N}} a_i x^i\right)  \star \left(\sum_{i \in \mathbb{N}} b_i x^i\right) := \sum_{i \in \mathbb{N}} a_i b_i x^i$$

This fits with Khosotrash's observation in a nice way:

$$\sin (x) = e^x \star \frac{x}{1+x^2}=\frac{1}{2i}\left(e^x \star\frac{1}{1-ix}-e^x \star\frac{1}{1+ix}\right)= \frac{1}{2i}(e^{ix}-e^{-ix})$$